# How to merge two multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge, array-push

I have two array:

```
$arr1 = array(
    'attributes' => array(
        'fruit'     => 'banana', 
    ),
);

$arr2 = array(
    'attributes' => array(
        'color'    => 'red', 
    ),
);

$result = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
```

The result is:

```
Array ( [attributes] => Array ( [color] => red ) )
```

But my expected result:

```
Array ( [attributes] => Array ( [color] => red [fruit] => banana ) )
```

What I am doing wrong? Should I use **array_merge** 
or maybe will be better and easier just to use **array_push** and use only  ('color' => 'red') ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`array_merge_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) is a great fit here.

```
$resultArray = array_merge_recursive($arr1, $arr2);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$result = array('attributes' => array_merge($arr1['attributes'], $arr2['attributes']));
print_r($result);
```

Comment: So your suggestion is to merge individually? What if there are 10 keys?

Comment: then we need to use  `array_merge_recursive()`  as you mentioned @Aniket Sahrawat